# How do i make my 'About Us' page into 2 columns

Tags: magento-1.7

Ive tried selecting the option to have my text into two columns but once i save it, it doesn't seem to change anything. Im not very familiar with coding please someone help.

This is was my text looks like

```
 <div class="page-title">  
<h1 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #888888;">About Us</span></h1>
</div>
<div class="col3-set">
<div class="col-1" style="text-align: center;">
<p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #99cc00;">Welcome to Come September, a place for beautiful clothing, unique jewellery and other fashion accessories.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Fashion is an art. Not only is it art, but it is an important and powerful. It encompasses texture, form, shape, colour, and more. The fashion we choose, shows the world who we are and who we want to be.&nbsp;&nbsp;It makes us stand out from the crowd, and helps us tell our story. Our clothing range start at size 8 and goes through to size 26.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Come September takes this self-expression seriously. We know you take your reputation, your image, and your comfort very seriously (not to mention your wallet!) That's why we search for and offer you only the most carefully chosen fashion clothes and accessories at only the best prices.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Remember &ndash; accessories are just as important as the clothes on your body and the shoes on your feet. Fashion accessories and bags have the ability to elevate and transform an outfit &ndash; ultimately allowing you to spend less money by updating existing clothing you already own. Not only that &ndash; but fashion accessories, from bracelets to hair accessories, help you to punctuate your style by adding a bit of glitz or drama.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Here you can choose from great-looking, affordable clothes, jewellery, handbags/clutches, hair accessories, clothing, and formal&nbsp;&nbsp;accessories. We are always thoughtfully updating what we offer &ndash; keeping an eye on trends while always maintaining an appreciation for the classics.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Enjoy looking through what we have. We'll help you build a collection of clothing and accessory staples from which you can draw every time you get dressed in the morning. Pieces you can come back to again and again. Pieces that make a statement about who you are, and who you'd like to be. Of course it's what's inside that matters, but we all need a little help to shine!</p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-family: Georgia, serif;"><span style="font-size: 24px;">Melissa Greggery</span></span></p>
</div>
</div>``
```

Answer (score 0):

This is CSS qst and will be closed. For future reference you should ask in stackoverflow.com

I will give you a hint here though.

```
<div class="page-title">  
<h1 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #888888;">About Us</span></h1>
</div>
<div class="col2-set">
<div class="col-2" style="text-align: center;">
<p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #99cc00;">Welcome to Come September, a place for beautiful clothing, unique jewellery and other fashion accessories.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Fashion is an art. Not only is it art, but it is an important and powerful. It encompasses texture, form, shape, colour, and more. The fashion we choose, shows the world who we are and who we want to be.&nbsp;&nbsp;It makes us stand out from the crowd, and helps us tell our story. Our clothing range start at size 8 and goes through to size 26.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Come September takes this self-expression seriously. We know you take your reputation, your image, and your comfort very seriously (not to mention your wallet!) That's why we search for and offer you only the most carefully chosen fashion clothes and accessories at only the best prices.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Remember &ndash; accessories are just as important as the clothes on your body and the shoes on your feet. Fashion accessories and bags have the ability to elevate and transform an outfit &ndash; ultimately allowing you to spend less money by updating existing clothing you already own. Not only that &ndash; but fashion accessories, from bracelets to hair accessories, help you to punctuate your style by adding a bit of glitz or drama.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Here you can choose from great-looking, affordable clothes, jewellery, handbags/clutches, hair accessories, clothing, and formal&nbsp;&nbsp;accessories. We are always thoughtfully updating what we offer &ndash; keeping an eye on trends while always maintaining an appreciation for the classics.</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">Enjoy looking through what we have. We'll help you build a collection of clothing and accessory staples from which you can draw every time you get dressed in the morning. Pieces you can come back to again and again. Pieces that make a statement about who you are, and who you'd like to be. Of course it's what's inside that matters, but we all need a little help to shine!</p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-family: Georgia, serif;"><span style="font-size: 24px;">Melissa Greggery</span></span></p>
</div>

<div class="col-2">
<p>your paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```